# Create subset of pandas dataframe based on continuity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a Pandas dataframe with a timeseries-index of about 3 millions row. This dataframe has several columns and I would like to create subsets out of this dataframe dependent on the continuity of the timeserie, based on the values in the columns. The data is not continues over all columns. By this, I mean that there are rows that has NaN in any of n columns, and in this case this means that it is not a continuously timeseries. I want to build subsets (B,C) out of the original dataframe (A), and these subsets should be a continuously timeseries with no NaN values in either column.

Example:

Datafram A

| predicted_at | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-21 11:00:00 UTC | 1002 | 202 |
| 2021-08-21 12:00:00 UTC | 123 | 432 |
| 2021-08-21 13:00:00 UTC | 1253 | 542 |
| 2021-08-21 14:00:00 UTC | 231 | NaN |
| 2021-08-21 15:00:00 UTC | 23 | 232 |
| 2021-08-21 16:00:00 UTC | 321 | 123 |
| 2021-08-21 17:00:00 UTC | 125 | 124 |

Subset B:

| predicted_at | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-21 11:00:00 UTC | 1002 | 202 |
| 2021-08-21 12:00:00 UTC | 123 | 432 |
| 2021-08-21 13:00:00 UTC | 1253 | 542 |

Subset C:

| predicted_at | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-21 15:00:00 UTC | 23 | 232 |
| 2021-08-21 16:00:00 UTC | 321 | 123 |
| 2021-08-21 17:00:00 UTC | 125 | 124 |

How would one proceed for this?

Comment: Why are Subset B and C the same in your example?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen edited

Comment: What do you want to do with this subsets? What should be the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumsum` to set continuous group:

```
df['subset'] = df.isna().any(axis=1).cumsum().loc[df.notna().all(axis=1)]
print(df)

# Output:
              predicted_at    x1     x2  subset
0  2021-08-21 11:00:00 UTC  1002  202.0     0.0
1  2021-08-21 12:00:00 UTC   123  432.0     0.0
2  2021-08-21 13:00:00 UTC  1253  542.0     0.0
3  2021-08-21 14:00:00 UTC   231    NaN     NaN
4  2021-08-21 15:00:00 UTC    23  232.0     1.0
5  2021-08-21 16:00:00 UTC   321  123.0     1.0
6  2021-08-21 17:00:00 UTC   125  124.0     1.0
```

Now you can do `groupby` or what you want.